# Building custom mouse-sharing software exclusively via a hard link (cable)?

Tags: windows, macos, protocols, kvm

I apologize if this isn't the appropriate forum for this, I'm not sure where else I'd ask.

I've spent hours trying to get even a brief introduction on creating a mouse sharing network, searching for the "How To's?" and "How do they work?" All I've come up with is endless pages pointing to [Synergy](http://symless.com/synergy/) and [Share Mouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com).

*One reason for my trouble is likely that I'm not familiar with the appropriate jargon to get me to the right places. The best I've gotten is that they usually (or always?) use a `virtual KVM desktop`, but beyond that I've hit a wall.*

I am trying to set up the sharing between a Windows PC and Mac Pro. The two systems share multiple screens, and different screens can be dynamically allocated to either system, on an as-needed basis.

I would like to try to roll my own mouse sharing software (along with file, etc), but with a few extra caveats over the current options available:

- *BOTH* systems can immediately take the roll of server (or share the load at all times)

  Currently, mouse sharing software assigns one system as a server, and the rest as clients. I won't always be using both systems, and might shut one off at a moment's notice (or kick the power cord, or whatever). With current mouse sharing, if the server gets shut off, then the clients are all without keyboard and mouse.

  For my own software, I'd like to maintain uninterrupted functionality at all times.
- No WiFi -> Connection exclusively through a hard link (cable)

  Again, current options can allow some [finagling](https://superuser.com/questions/746838/how-can-i-use-a-crossover-cable-with-synergy-or-sharemouse) to allow crossover cables to be used between the systems. This has the drawback that only one system is truly connected to the internet, and the other is piggybacking off of it.

  For my own, I would like both systems to have ethernet modem connections at all times (again, in the case that I'm using one or the other, or maybe one is down). The particular connection is not a huge concern - I'm happy to connect the two through a crossover cable, or USB, or thunderbolt or whatever.

  An additional reason for the hard link between the two is speed. I don't want any lag between the two screens when the cursor crosses over, and I would like to have the most optimized environment for sharing clipboard and drag/drop files. WiFi is undesirable, and I'm sure not all connection options are created equal.
- No Virtual Machines (If possible...)

  In the interest of not including more than is absolutely necessary, I was wondering if there can be a more direct protocol created between the two systems, opposed to having to mount a virtual environment, and pass everything through that? This goes back to speed - I can't imagine that a virtual environment would be anywhere near as quick as a direct system-to-system protocol.

My reason for wanting to roll my own is to get the *exact* functionality I seek - with nothing more and nothing less - as well as to improve my coding prowess. Whether or not this is the case, I also feel like I have a safer setup when the two systems are not sharing the same internet connection or communicating through WiFi; hard links are reassuring, and I have more control on what can be permitted through the connection.

I'm sorry that I don't have any code to include in this, but I honestly don't know the first place to begin. There doesn't seem to be a lot of readily available resources on the topic, and my ignorance with this kind of coding/integration is a major handicap.

Any pointers, topics to look into, existing similar project and so on, are all welcome. I'll take anything I can get. Hopefully the answers will steer enough away from opinion that the question can be valid.